# Mocking the 3rd party components with concrete class

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I am desiging component which refers to a assembly deisgend by a third party.
In my component i am creating an instance of the object exposed from the third party.

Now i wanted to do a unit testing for the component which i have writen by mocking the 3rd party component. But the component provided by the 3rd party is a cconcrete class.

how should i go ahed write unit tests for the component which i have written

Answer (score 2):

One way you could get round this would be to have a factory that provides the concrete class from the 3rd party and inject that into your class.  Then you can simply wrap the newing up of their component in the factory but provide a mock factory that returns your mock 3rd party component for use with your tests.

Answer (score 0):

You may either go with [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/moles/) for VS2010 and [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for VS2012. Both frameworks enable you to write mocks / shims of concrete objects.

You can just create mocks of objects of the third party dll and change the method behaviors.